# utf8, newcommand and umlaut

Tags: macros, unicode

In my document, which is encoded as `utf8` throughout (hopefully), umlaute etc. in the document body are put out correctly, but those defined in a `\newcommand` are not. I have tried some alternatives to writing the unlaute plain, and `\symbol` works, while the international accent does not, and I'd rather not use it since it is a little cumbersome.

See the following example:

```
\newcommand{\myPlace}{Örtlichkeit}
\newcommand{\myWhat}{\"{O}rtlichkeit}
\newcommand{\myHmm}{Stra\symbol{255}e}

\documentclass{scrlttr2} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\myPlace

\myWhat

\myHmm

ÖÄÜäöüß
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Thanks! That was a really stupid error. I adapted the document, and changed the inputenc. I even thought "Maybe I should check the position of the newcommand before I open a question ..." :/ If you put this is an answer, I will gladly mark it as correct. e: Oh, the other mistake was even more stupid ... not my day today!

Comment: If you want to leave the definitions at the top, you should use the LaTeX internal character representation (LICR) of the characters; so `\newcommand{\myPlace}{\"{O}rtlichkeit}` and `\newcommand{\myHmmm}{Stra\ss e}`. It's the `inputenc` package that assigns the desired meaning to the non ASCII characters and using them before loading the package can lead to puzzling results.

Comment: @Narretz - I've resubmitted my comment as an answer, per your suggestion. I've also fixed the typo in the second `\newcommand` instruction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you move the three `\newcommand` instructions to a point *after* the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instruction, you won't experience the problems you're reporting.

*Addendum* -- A comment provided by @egreg -- If you wanted to leave the definitions at the top, you should use the LaTeX internal character representation (LICR) of the characters: `\newcommand{\myPlace}{\"{O}rtlichkeit}` and `\newcommand{\myHmmm}{Stra\ss e}`. It's the `inputenc` package that assigns the desired meaning to the non-ASCII characters, and using them before loading the package is what leads to puzzling results.

Comment: If you like, you can move also my comment in your answer.

Comment: Move @egreg's comments *after* your answer and you will experience a full answer.

Comment: For a full answer babel shorthands are missing, they are available after package `babel` is loaded and activated in `\begin{document}` for the main language by default.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek My point was how to have the commands safely at the top, which can be handy in some applications; your useful comment adds that those shortcuts *can't* be used there.

Comment: @egreg -- Thanks for your kind suggestion; I've posted your comment as an addendum to my answer.

Comment: @egreg Also babel shorthands could be used there, there are only needed as active characters.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I wouldn't recommend to the general public starting a file with `\catcode` declarations. `;-)`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Please feel free to append your comments about use of the `babel`-related instructions to my answer. I hadn't brought them up in my answer because the OP's MWE didn't actually make use of `babel`'s capabilities -- other than to load the package with the `ngerman` option set.